# React-Redux, two same components, but different mapStateToProps

Tags: react-redux

I need two components that have the same functionality but I want to map a different state property to the props.  How do I keep it DRY (not just have two separate components with mostly the same code)?  Here is a much simplified version of one of the components:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

class MyComponent extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){

  }
  render (){
    return (
      <div className=""> 
        <div>
          {this.props.someDate}
        </div>

      </div>
    )    
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
      someData: state.publications.someData
    }
}

export default connect( mapStateToProps, {})(MyComponent)
```

The other component is exactly the same, but mapStateToProps should look like this:

```
   function mapStateToProps(state){
        return {
          someData: state.articles.someData
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would also be very interested in this!

Comment: Why not simply export two components created by applying `connect` to each `mapStateToProps` and `MyComponent`?

Comment: can you elaborate?  Is this all in one file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of connecting `myComponent` to redux state you can do it with their parents. 
Parent component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import Child from 'Child.js'

const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
       someData: someData: state.publications.someData
   };
};

 class Parent extends Component {
       render (){
           retrun <Child data={this.props.someData}
       }
 }
 export default connect( mapStateToProps, null)(Parent)
```

Then you'll get reusable child like this:

```
....
export default class Child extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <div className=""> 
              <div>{this.props.data}</div>
           </div>
        )    
    } 
}
```